# Electron shell bombardment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

If you bombard an electron shell with a photon below the critical level to promote the electron to a higher state, will the shell absorb nothing and the photon get deflected with the same amount of frequency/energy that it came with initially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. What you describe is the quantum mechanical picture behind the elastic [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering). For the actual calculation, see [R. Loudon, The quantum theory of light](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198501765), Chapter 8.8.